# javascript - pass object via post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, object

I have an object that looks like this

var obj = {
  p1 : true,
  p2 : true,
  p3 : false
}

I am looking to try and pass this object as part of a post request.

however on the other end (in php) all I get is

> [object Object]

How can I send an object via post?

basically what I am trying to do is

I have an input that is hidden and is created like so

`<input id="obj" type="hidden" name="obj[]">`

which is part of a hidden form.

when a button is pressed I have

```
$(#obj).val(obj);
$('form').submit();
```

---

Please no suggestions to use ajax as I must do it this way as it is to download a dynamically created file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to serialize/convert the object to a string before submitting it. You can use [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) for this.

```
$('#obj').val(jQuery.param(obj));
```

Comment: A+ first one to read the whole question, and your answer works perfect too :) Will accept asap

Comment: even works recursively `{a: {b: 'c', d: {e: 'f', g: 'h'}, i: 'j'}` => `a[b]=c&a[d][e]=f&a[d][g]=h&i=j`

Answer (score 14):

You might consider using [JSON](http://json.org) notation to send the object to the server. <s>If you include a [JSON parser/renderer](http://www.json.org/js.html) in your page,</s> *(it's built in on all modern browsers now, and also IE8 in standards mode)* you can convert the object into a string preserving its full object graph. Most server-side languages now have JSON parsing available for them (in PHP it's `json_decode`, for instance). You can put that string in your hidden form field before sending the form.

That would look like this:

```
$('#obj').val(JSON.stringify(obj));
$('form').submit();
```

...and your server-side would see a string in the form

```
{ "p1" : true, "p2" : true, "p3" : false }
```

Comment: Please read the whole question. The form is needed as it is downloading a dynamically generated file, You cannot cause a file download from ajax data.

I cannot store the file that is created anywhere either so, generating the file via the ajax call and returning a url will not work either.

Comment: @Hailwood: Can't believe I missed that. Fixed.

Comment: @T.J. Cheers, Your new answer will work. However i am using @Matt's answer :) (ps, you get an upvote from me)

Comment: @Hailwood: Glad Matt's solution will work for you, it's all about having options. :-)

Comment: Exactly, Actually I do prefer this option, but I am including jquery already, unless it has a built in JSON parser I dont really want to include another library. Most browsers now have a JSON parser already, but... IE6...

Comment: @Hailwood: jQuery has a JSON *parser* built in (`jQuery.parseJSON`) but you actually want the opposite, the stringifier, which it doesn't. FWIW, json2.js [minified](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) is 3,408 bytes. If you can include that in another script file you're already including in the page, I doubt it'll make any difference. If you can't, then you have the overhead of the additional HTTP request... Have fun!

Comment: JSON.stringify seems to be a built-in since ECMAScript 5.1 (ECMA-262) https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/stringify

Comment: @DestyNova: Yes. Back in 2010, though, the standard was brand-new and many widely-used browsers didn't have support built-in yet...