# array of objects as parameters on request POST axios

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, vue.js, axios

I am working on a project with vue.js and to handle my `AJAX` requests I use `Axios`, I wonder if it is possible to pass as a parameter to a `POST` request an array of objects, of this type:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'max'}, {id: 2, name: 'jhon'}, {id: 3, name: 'anna'}]
```

If possible, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - pass object via post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255848/javascript-pass-object-via-post)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 9):

> Sure!

```
let arrOfObj = [
  { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  { name: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' }
]

axios.post('url_here',arrOfObj)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's very possible

```
let data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'max'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'jhon'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'anna'}
];

let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('data',JSON.stringify(data));

axios.post('/url`',formdata)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err)
```

On the receiving end (assuming it's PHP & Laravel)

```
$data = json_decode($request->data);
```

then loop through $data as it's a normal array

Answer (score 1):

[Lema's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62019219/8326848) was the only one that worked for me while using axios + vue + .net Core.

I was trying to send a post to my backend which was expecting an array. Following Lema's implementation I received an string and then deserialized the json string to the type I was expecting.

```
    public IActionResult PostMethod([FromForm]string serialized_object_name){
         var expectedArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArrayTypeNeeded[]>(serialized_object_name);
    }
```